# Flutter blue is not listing available devices

Tags: flutter

I am trying to list the available ble devices but the list is empty

```
flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));
var subscription = flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
  for (ScanResult r in results) {
    for (ScanResult r in results) {
      print('${r.device.name} found! rssi: ${r.rssi}');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: - Did you add all appropriate permissions that are required in AndroidManifest.xml as per required in the official documentation of the package?
- Are the other devices that you want to discover... discoverable? Some devices have to be switched on "Discovery Mode"
- Also, I don't think that you need two for loops there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All permissions are added according to documentation tried all solutions but results in empty scan redult

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: try enabling gps in the smartphone and then recompile again

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```dart
//Get bluetooth results
Future<List<ScanResult>> bluetoothScan()async{
  List<ScanResult> bluetoothDevices = [];
  FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;
  //Stop scan before restarting scan too prevent errors when trying to scan
  await flutterBlue.stopScan();
  print("Start scan");
  // Start scanning
  List<dynamic> foundDevices = await flutterBlue.startScan(
    timeout: const Duration(
      seconds: 10,
    ),
  ).asStream().toList();
  await flutterBlue.stopScan();
  print("Scan end");
  for(dynamic devices in foundDevices){
    for(ScanResult device in devices){
      bluetoothDevices.add(device);
    }
  }
  return bluetoothDevices;
}
```

However the device name is empty for some reason